# code to brighten a placeholder on a textarea

Tags: html, css

a easy question is there any way I could brighten this html *placeholder*

```
<textarea placeholder="brighten this"></textarea>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `brighten`? How should the result be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean style it with css you can use something like this

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: yellow;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: yellow;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: yellow;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: yellow;  
}
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/ux9mfoqu/) showing you